# Converting a timer switch to basic switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I'm replacing an old timer switch to our closets and there is a blue, black and white wire attached to the old switch.  Do I need a three way switch or do I get a normal switch and cap the blue off?

[image]

Comment: How many switches control the closet lights?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: Are you sure the blue wire isn’t green?

Comment: It controls 1 light

Comment: https://s.amsu.ng/Z5vjRFxjefLN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like your switch requires a neutral; if your new switch is a snap switch (aka regular light switch) cap the white wire off. The black and blue don’t matter on a snap switch and can be on either brass screw; one is hot the other is the load.